24.04 installer not showing internal ssd in macbook air 2014
Hi hoping someone can help me. I'm trying to install ubuntu 24.04 on a 2014 intel macbook air. Only the internal ssd is not showing in the installer. Nor is it showing in disks or gparted.
22.04 regnozised the drive right away and installed right away. Once 22.04 was installed I tried the 24.04 installer again thinking it might recognise the drive now it's ext4 formated. Still nothing.
I've seen a post from a number of years ago from a user called Saul. Only that was a pre 22.04 release. It suggested adding intel_iommu=off in the grub menu. I'll be honest and say I'm a noob, so don't know what this means but  have tried it to no avail (I could have done it wrong)
Again noob, so not sure if this is possible but could the kernel update be missing a driver that 22.04 has?
EDIT - Partial Solution Found
I was putting intel_iommu=off in the wrong place.
22.04 upgrade on macbook hard disk disappeared
The installer now works but it boots into busybox so something still isn't right.

I know it has been some time now since this question was asked but I got into this same problem yesterday.
First, your temporary solution did help to install the OS, but it kinda extends to being able to open it as well.
I've looked here for an answer that I'll share here:
First, to open the OS for the first time:
When booting, grub should be showing you a screen before opening busybox, there, you:

[...] press the e key.
You should be able to see and edit the commands associated with the
highlighted kernel.
Go down to the line starting with linux and add your parameter intel_iommu=off to its end.
Now press Ctrl + x to boot.

Now, after the system is open:


From a terminal (or after pressing Alt + F2) run:
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
(or use sudo nano if gksudo or gedit are not available) and enter your password.

Find the line starting with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and append intel_iommu=off to its end. For example:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=off"
Save the file and close the editor.

Finally, start a terminal and run:
sudo update-grub
to update GRUB's configuration file (you probably need to enter your password).


On the next reboot, the kernel should be started with the boot parameter. To permanently remove it, simply remove the parameter from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and run sudo update-grub again.
To verify your changes, you can see exactly what parameters your kernel booted with by executing cat /proc/cmdline..


Do you know what intel_iommu is? I had stopped trying to get around it as I wasn't sure what it did. From google it seems to be needed in virtual machines? Not sure if that's right
